# Passing parent component viewmodel to child component viewmodel using knockout js not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, knockout.js

I am trying to access parent viewmodel function in a child component viewmodel and I have been able to successfully do so using the following:

```
<!-- ko component: { name: "component-name", params: { claimId: claimId, $data } }--><!-- /ko -->
```

So here I am passing the `$data` of the current component to the child while binding the child component. For some reason `$data` is throwing exception in IE.

Here's the screenshot of the exception:

[image]

Comment: Please post the message of the exception!

Comment: I have added the screenshot. It's only happening in IE

Comment: The error points to the **line 172 in your init.js file**... Can you post the your code from there?